# How to generate an AES key with AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding for encrypting and decrypting

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

I'm trying to create a AES key with this code

```java
    public static SecretKey generateSecretKey() {

        KeyGenerator generator;
        try {

            generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(StaticHandler.AES_KEY_MODE); // Is "AES"
            generator.init(StaticHandler.AES_KEY_SIZE); // The AES key size in number of bits // Is "128"

            return generator.generateKey();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

however using this code for encrypting/decrypting

```java
    public static String encrypt(String data, SecretKey secret, Charset charset) {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);

            return new String(cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes()), charset);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    public static String decrypt(String data, @NonNull SecretKey secret, Charset charset) {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret);

            return new String(cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes()), charset);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

gets the error 
`java.security.InvalidKeyException: Parameters missing`

I'm guessing I need to add some salt, though I don't know how to do that with a generated key. I would like to stray away from generating a password but if it's a securely generated password I wouldn't mind.

Edit: Just an after thought, should I use GCM or CBC encryption if I'm sending packets through the network? Remember I'm using randomly generated keys and I am not going to keep them for sessions, randomly generated per client and server session.

Comment: What line is the exception thrown from?

Comment: If I remember correctly it is the cipher.init() method call. I can't check at moment of writing.

Comment: You may check some examples for encryption code https://gusto77.wordpress.com/2017/10/30/encryption-reference-project/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need salt and your key is actuallly fine. **CBC mode requires an IV** (Initialization Vector), [see wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation), and IV should be different for each piece of data encrypted, but each decryption must use the same value as the corresponding encryption did. (added) For CBC, though not some other modes, it is also vital for security that IVs not be predictable by an adversary; the simplest and most common way to achieve both uniqueness and unpredictability is to use a *secure* Random Number (aka Bit) Generator such as Java's `SecureRandom`. If you want to know about other methods, that is not really a programming issue and is better suited on crypto.SX or security.SX, where there are already several Qs.

You can either generate the IV explicitly and specify it to both encrypt and decrypt, or allow the encrypt operation to generate the IV itself, fetch it from the encrypt Cipher, and specify it to the decrypt Cipher. In either case the encryptor must provide the value the decryptor will use; a common approach is to simply concatenate the IV with the ciphertext (making it very easy to keep them matched up properly) but again there are other approaches discussed on crypto and security. See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/security/java-cryptography-architecture-jca-reference-guide.html in the sections named "Initializing a Cipher Object" (the two paragraphs just after the boxed block of method declarations) and "Managing Algorithm Parameters".

---

Also **don't store ciphertext in a `String`**. Java `String` is designed to handle valid characters not arbitrary bytes. 'Decoding' ciphertext to a String and 'encoding' it back to binary will almost always lose or alter some of the data, especially if you allow the Charset to differ at the two ends, and with modern cryptography any change at all to the ciphertext will destroy all or much of your data. Since ciphertext *is* bytes, it is best to handle it as `byte[]`; if that is not possible because you want to put it in something that *is* characters like a URL, use one of the many schemes designed to encode arbitrary bytes to text so that they can be recovered correctly: base64 (3 or 4 major variants, plus many minor ones), base32, hexadecimal/base16, URL 'percent' encoding, MIME quoted-printable, yencode, Kermit, PPP, etc. j8+ [`java.util.Base64`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Base64.html) provides the newer base64 variants (i.e. not uuencode).

Conversely, although 'plaintext' in modern crypto can really be *any* form of data, if yours truly is text and belongs in a `String` you should encode it using a suitable Charset before encrypting, and decode using the *same* Charset after decrypting, i.e.

```
 byte[] ctext = encCipher.doFinal (input.getBytes(charset));
 ...
 String output = new String (decCipher.doFinal (ctext), charset);
```

While the 'best' Charset may vary depending on your data, if you don't know what the data will be or don't want to bother analyzing it, `UTF-8` is reasonably good for most text data and very popular and standard.

Comment: Could you also add that the IV must be unpredictable?

Comment: I was going to use byte[] instead of string at one point but first I wanted the encryption to work. If I get it work with your answer, I’ll set it to solved if I remember to.

Comment: @kelalaka: excellent point. I was in a bit of a rush and that slipped my mind.